# Can jsfiddle host an external CSS file?

Tags: hosting, jsfiddle, imgur

I wish to share a jsfiddle.  TinyMCE is also involved, and needs an external CSS file.  I don't wish to host the external CSS file on my server.

Is it possible to do this just with jsfiddle?

If not, is there a free non-registrar required service like imgur where I could upload a file and add it as an external resource to jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes they exist, but recommendations are not on topic for stackoverflow. Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. See also [What exactly is a recommendation question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question).

Comment: @max  I slightly changed the question.  Think it is still not on topic?  Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately yes, try asking on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21641/imgur-for-css-files?noredirect=1#comment31919_21641 Thanks max. Tried but no go.  I will try the other.